# Command line compile using cl.exe?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

Am trying to use the Visual Studio Express 2010 C++ compiler without using the IDE. I found cl.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin. However am having a few difficulties. Firstly it gave me a warning pop up when i type cl saying 'Program cannot start because mspdb100.dll is missing from your computer.'

So i add C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE to the system path and then try again, but this time:

> fatal error C1510: Cannot load language resource clui.dll.

Any idea how to solve this so i can compile? Also how would i set up the path so i can just type 'cl main.cpp' etc, from within a solution folder that does not contain cl.exe. At the moment i have to be inside bin folder. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't VS install a shortcut/menu entry for a cmd shell with all the right settings?

Comment: There's a win32_all_vars.bat or sth inside the VS folder, execute that and try again.

Comment: @Mat: Yea but that isn't exactly an elegant solution.

Comment: Not elegant? A single click to get a proper compiler environment set up? ... Just look at what the shortcut does and reproduce that in the most "elegant" way you like.

Comment: Thought you meant opening the IDE and running command line from there every time.

Comment: Ran vcvars32.bat, still not working. Can only compile if open a command prompt from inside the ide.

Comment: @DanielGratz: you need to pass certain parameters to it, IIRC. Look at what exactly the "Visual Studio Command Prompt" item in the start menu does. It initializes an environment where the compiler is accessible. So look at how that is defined. On my machine, it looks like calling `vcvarsall.bat x86` does the trick, if called with `"%programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC` as your working dir.

Answer (score 55):

Try starting the Visual Studio Command Prompt from

```
Start->
    All Programs ->
        Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ->
            Visual Studio Tools ->
                Visual Studio Command Prompt 2010
```

Alternatively, you can set up the environment by running this in a command prompt:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
```

(note: this will leave your environment set up after running.)

(note2: change `x86` as desired. options are `x86`, `ia64`, `amd64`, `x86_amd64`, `x86_ia64`)

From there you can run `cl.exe`. If you want this to be automatically done and undone whenever you run `cl`, create a batch file with this content:

```
@echo off
%comspec% /c ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 && cl.exe %*"
```

(the `/c` tells the command prompt to end the session after running this command, so your environment returns to normal.)

From there, name it `cl.bat`. Put this in a folder somewhere, and add the path to that folder to your `PATH` environment variable, making sure it comes *before* the path to `cl.exe`, so that this `cl.bat` is executed whenever you type `cl` instead of `cl.exe`

I recommend you just put `cl.bat` in your `system32/` folder, it should come before `cl.exe`'s path on a default installation.

Alternatively, you can add it in any order and always type `cl.bat`, or name it something else so there's no confusion.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `vcvarsall.bat` as jsvk suggested:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
```

After that, use `devenv.exe` to build your stuff if you keep yourself safe from a lot of head-aches:

```
devenv solutionfile.sln /build [ solutionconfig ] [ /project projectnameorfile [ /projectconfig name ] ]
```

There are a lot of other command line switches which you can check with `devenv /?`.

Answer (score 6):

This is a quite simple and strait forward task. Firstly add the compiler path to system path.:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin; Next, open command prompt and change directory to your source folder; Then execute the vcvars32.bat file to setup the environment for using vc++ on x86; After this, you can now type cl to compile your program

Answer (score 5):

I have multiple versions of VS installed;  I create a little .BAT file for each version, placed somewhere in the path, that calls the relevant "vcvarsall.bat".  e.g. "vc9.bat" calls vcvarsall.bat for VS2008, while "vc10.bat" calls vcvarsall.bat for VS2010.  I can open a normal command window as usual, type "vc9", and presto, that command window is ready to compile etc using VS2008.

Comment: This is a great idea, I don't know why I have not done this before.

Comment: May we see your batch file? Perhaps a github gist or code pastei?

Answer (score 3):

That errors occurs when the linker runs out of memory.
You can use the x64 tool architecture Visual studio tools.

msbuild command line:

```
msbuild myproject.vcxproj /p:PreferredToolArchitecture=x64
```

Or, better yet, add it to the project's settings in the .vcxproj.
 To specify the 64-bit version of the compiler and tools, add the following property group element to the Myproject.vcxproj project file after the Microsoft.Cpp.default.props  element:

```
<PropertyGroup>  
    <PreferredToolArchitecture>x64</PreferredToolArchitecture>  
</PropertyGroup>
```

These options will make Visual studio use the tools under the amd64 architecture folders (according to the target architecture):
VC\bin\amd64
VC\bin\amd64_x86
VC\bin\amd64_arm

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293607.aspx