# CMake with Visual Studio 2012/2013 broken?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

CMake 2.8.10.2 for Windows just refused to configure a project for me with Visual Studio 2012 (under Windows 7)

It seems like CMake adds some settings that are no longer supported by the Microsoft compiler.
  *LINK : fatal error LNK1117: syntax error in option 'manifest:embed'*

I tried and got the same result with a very basic cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
add_executable(test test.cpp)
```

Is there a work-around?

The output window show:

```
The C compiler identification is MSVC 17.0.51106.1
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 17.0.51106.1
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 11
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 11 -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
  11.0/VC/bin/cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/tmp/testCmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com
  CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln /build Debug /project cmTryCompileExec3122367237



  Microsoft (R) Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Version 11.0.51106.1.

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp.  All rights reserved.

  1>------ Build started: Project: cmTryCompileExec3122367237, Configuration:
  Debug Win32 ------

  1> Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01
  for 80x86

  1> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  1> 

  1> cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D
  "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise
  /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"cmTryCompileExec3122367237.dir\Debug\\"
  /Fd"C:/tmp/testCmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTryCompileExec3122367237.pdb"
  /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:prompt /Zm1000 testCCompiler.c

  1> 

  1> testCCompiler.c

  1>LINK : fatal error LNK1117: syntax error in option 'manifest:embed'

  ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped
  ==========





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):



Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: I have been using VS2012 for over 1 month on several projects. VTK, ITK, DCMTK, GDCM all build fine as well as my code. I am using CMake 2.8.10.2. Although I very rarely build for 32 bit any more.

Comment: I have also used CMake with Visual Studio 2012 for quite some time without problems. I reinstalled Visual Studio a few days ago, installed the latest updates, and then the problem surfaced.

Comment: From the error message: The cl.exe (VS C++ compiler ) can not be located - where is your cl.exe installed? Try a command line compile with cl (as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865432/command-line-compile-using-cl-exe) to figure out if your compiler is working. Maybe your VS installation is messed up.

Comment: @Vertexwahn Your statement is not true. The compiler is found, but a test compilation failed with the error message given by jgaa.

Comment: It states `Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 11 -- broken` this means broken. If simple test code cannot be compiled, the compiler is regarded as broken. I am working with 2.8.10.2 and 2.8.12.2 and also confirm no problems with Cmake and VS 2012. You can try to compile the test code by yourself as manifest:embed is not per se wrong.

Answer (score 3):

CMake 2.8 works well with Visual Studio 2012.

In the log you provided, note that CMake invokes Visual Studio 2012, which in turn invokes **the compiler of Visual Studio 2008** (15.x; the compiler of VS2012 should be 17.x):

> Microsoft (R) Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Version 11.0.51106.1.
>
> [...]
>
> 1> Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for 80x86

This probably means your installation of VS2012 is configured to use the toolset of VS2008. It probably means the same thing is happening when you build directly in Visual Studio and not only via CMake.

This may be caused by unintended changes to the property sheet `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props` (or `Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user.props`, if you are building for x64). These files reside in
`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0`. If you see the directories of VS2008 referenced in any of these property sheets, this is likely the source of your problems.

To fix this, you can either manually edit the said file (completely removing the XML elements that refer to VS2008 folders), or just follow the steps given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20531205/289770):

> 1. Open any C++ project in Visual Studio 2012.
> 2. Open **View -> Other Windows -> Property Manager**
> 3. Double click on **Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user**
> 4. Go to **VC++ Directories**
> 5. Rows which have been changed are bold. on all bold rows, click inside
>      the text field, then on the Dropdown menu select **inherit from parent
>      or Project Defaults**
> 6. Click **Apply**, **save** and then close the dialog.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the same issue for me with Cmake and Visual Studio 2013, even though I was trying to compile a 64-bit build.

Answer (score 0):

This did not work for me. However I was able to delete the offending file (C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props) and Visual Studio just recreated the file. Problem solved for both VS2012 and 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting error:

LINK : fatal error LNK1117: syntax error in option 'manifest:embed'

It happened under Windows 7, Visual Studio 2013 Community.

I tried many solutions, the only one that worked was to remove Visial Studio 2010 entirely from my computer. Nothing else worked.
I got it tracked down to an issue, that inside VS2013 the variable $VCInstallDir was still pointing to 2010 installation. This consequently caused wrong LibarayPath setting and wrong toolchain execs used (even though I has proper "PlatformToolset" setting).

To sum up:

1. you need to have proper "PlatformToolset" setting in you project and identical setting in all your library projects it depends on
2. you need to make sure correct library directory is used, by checking if $LibraryPath is correct and unless you override it directly in your project settings it will depend on $VCInstallDir via Visual Studio internal automation, so check that variable as well
3. to solve issue 2 you will probably have to remove Visual Studio 2010, since it makes a mess and probably there is no other solution.