# Visual C++ 2012 missing mspdb110.dll

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, cmd

I am trying to compile on cmd using cl and it says that I'm missing mspdb110.dll.
Anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Edit: I added this file path to PATH `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin` and the file is a standard hello world program

Comment: Did you try re-installing Visual Studio?

Comment: Tell us what are the commands you are using to compile, and the code you are trying to compile. Also tell us the commands you are using to link as well.

Comment: You must use the Visual Studio Command Prompt to get the console session setup properly.  That change to PATH was not enough.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to execute cl.exe from the command line, you need several environment variables added/modified. See here for further details:
[Command line compile using cl.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865432/command-line-compile-using-cl-exe)

The version mentioned in that post is VS2010, for VS2012, you should be running 'Developer Command Prompt for VS2012', which will set the variables for you.