# Compilation Error in VS Studio compiling Fortran code

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, fortran, compiler-warnings

I am getting this error while compiling my Fortran code in VS Studio:

```
warning #31001: The dll for reading and writing the pdb (for example, mspdb110.dll) could not be found on your path.
```

I also looked to change the Base Platform Toolset in Project Properties, but in VS 2019 IDE I couldn't find this option to edit it.
I am using Intel Compiler 2021. I have also tried upgrading my VS Studio to latest version but the problem persists.
Please tell how to fix this.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We need much more detail about your project and your software settings. What kind of pdb do you use?

Comment: Perhaps related (but with an error instead of a warning) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180610/visual-c-2012-missing-mspdb110-dll

Comment: @VladimirF I uninstalled and installed compiler, Visual Studio and fortran runtime again. Thanks Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is saying that your Visual Studio is misconfigured. Make sure that you have the "Desktop Development for C++" and "Windows 10 SDK" components of Visual Studio installed (see https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/installing-microsoft-visual-studio-2019-for-use-with-intel-compilers.html) You may need to uninstall both the Intel compiler and Visual Studio, then reinstall.

Comment: I uninstalled compiler and Visual Studio and reinstalled them. It worked Sir. Thanks a lot sir !